# whole xls page should appear with white background

Tags: ireport

I'm using iReport 3.7.0 and  generating an output in excel format.I want to show xls output with no grid view i.e whole page should appear with white background.How may I do that? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with JasperReports/iReport. Perhaps because the grid lines are not part of the cell format, instead they are a configuration option on a per-sheet basis.

In case you are exporting the Excel file from your own application, you can do your own postprocessing using Apache POI: Open the .xls file, change the setting, save the file.

The necessary property is **[HSSFSheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html).[setDisplayGridlines](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setDisplayGridlines%28boolean%29)**:

```
public void setDisplayGridlines(boolean show)
    //Sets whether the gridlines are shown in a viewer.
```

Also take a look at the other grid-related methods, some of them might be relevant, too.